# Repeated content (sub-template) in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a template which contains (in part) exactly the same content repeated two or three times with minor changes to the bindings, eg:

```
<div class="xyz-state0" data-ng-hide="data.error || !data.states[0].name">
    <div class="xyz-content">
        <img data-ng-src="{{data.states[0].image}}" width="48" height="48">
        <span>{{data.states[0].name}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="xyz-state1" data-ng-hide="data.error || !data.states[1].name">
    <div class="xyz-content">
        <img data-ng-src="{{data.states[1].image}}" width="48" height="48">
        <span>{{data.states[1].name}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I write this to avoid duplicating this HTML?  This is specific to its parent view (it won't be used anywhere else) so creating a full-blown widget seems wrong.

Basically I want something similar to ngRepeat, but I can't use that for the following reasons:

- I need a specific (and different) style on each parent div.
- I need to render a specific number of divs (2 in this case, 3 in another) regardless of whether or not they exist in the scope (ie. data.states could only have 1 element in it, but it still needs to create both divs).
- In the other case the items need to be rendered out of order (first 1, then 0, then 2).

I've managed to get a template fragment in a separate HTML file and included it with `ngInclude`, but I don't know how to get a single name in its new scope to refer to a specific item.  My first attempt was this, which doesn't work:

```
<div class="xyz-state0" data-ng-include="'state.tpl.html'" data-ng-init="state=data.state[0]"></div>
<div class="xyz-state1" data-ng-include="'state.tpl.html'" data-ng-init="state=data.state[1]"></div>
```

I suspect I could probably do it with a custom controller, but that seems like a heavy solution too.  What's the Right Way™?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this seems to do the trick (thanks to [pfooti](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26373426/43534) for the hint).  I'm still not entirely happy with it as the directive is registered globally, whereas I really only want it in this one place.

**state.tpl.html:**

```
<div class="xyz-content" data-ng-show="state.name">
    <img data-ng-src="{{state.image}}" width="48" height="48" />
    <span>{{state.name}}</span>
</div>
```

**view.tpl.html:**

```
    <div data-xyz-state="data.states[0]" class="xyz-state0"
         data-ng-hide="data.error"></div>
    <div data-xyz-state="data.states[1]" class="xyz-state1"
         data-ng-hide="data.error"></div>
```

**app.js:**

```
app.directive('xyzState', [function() {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'state.tpl.html',
        scope: {
            state: '=xyzState',
        },
    };
}]);
```

Interestingly it *doesn't* work if I try to declare the introducing element as `<xyz-state ...>` instead of `<div data-xyz-state="" ...>`, despite the docs saying that this ought to work too.  I assume there's some sort of validation thing interfering here.

Comment: you will need to do a `restrict: 'E'` if you want to use it as an element instead of attribute. And keep in mind that you can set the class programmatically if you're really doing states[0] as state0 and so forth. Check out ng-class for that.

Comment: I've used `ng-class` to set classes programmatically in some other contexts, but I'm not sure how it would help here.  Unless you're suggesting something like `ng-class="{'xyz-state0':$index==0,'xyz-state1':$index==1}"` -- I think that's much less readable than what I have.  (Although I admit that this would allow me to use `ng-repeat` for this case, though not the other one.)

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty much a textbook case for a custom directive. Define a directive, and then you can do

```
<state ng-repeat="item in data.states" item="item">.
```

Alternatively, if a custom directive is too much overkill (depends on whether you'll be reusing that view component elsewhere, mainly), you could just put an ng-repeat on the entire div. The only real issue is the class="xyz-stateN" stuff, but I bet you could hoke that up with ng-class usage.

EDIT:

if you do an ng-repeat, you can just use the $index key (as long as you're always counting up from zero and the state class is the same as the index). Something like

```
<div ng-class="{{'xyz-state'+$index}}" ng-repeat="state in data.states" data-ng-hide="data.error || !state.name">
    <div class="xyz-content">
        <img data-ng-src="{{state.image}}" width="48" height="48">
        <span>{{state.name}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Would probably work fine. All that said, it's almost always worth making a directive in my opinion. Code gets recycled all the time, plus you can be cautious with namespacing and modularizing if that makes you nervous.

Comment: I think you need to re-read my question.  I've mentioned that it's not going to be used elsewhere and that ng-repeat doesn't do what I want.

Comment: I agree with the ng-repeat solution. Your problem seems to be more with the array than with the view.

If you focus on making the states-array in the correct order/format with custom (or prebuilt) filters you might get a slick solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an FYI, I later revisited this code and decided to do it like this instead: (I'm letting my original answer stand as that is more like what I was originally asking for, and they both seem reasonable in different cases.)

**view.tpl.html**

```
    <div data-ng-repeat="state in data.states" data-ng-if="!data.error"
         data-ng-class="state.class">
        <div class="xyz-content" data-ng-show="state.name">
            <img data-ng-src="{{state.image}}" width="48" height="48" />
            <span>{{state.name}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**app.js**

```
...
while ($scope.data.states.length < 2)
    $scope.data.states.push({});
$scope.data.states[0].class = 'xyz-state1';
$scope.data.states[1].class = 'xyz-state2';
...
```

I've done something similar for the other (3-item) case, except there as I wanted to rearrange the order of the items I added an `order` property for the desired order in the controller and then used `data-ng-repeat="button in data.buttons|orderBy:'order'"` in the view.

This does mean that a bit of view definitions (display order and CSS classes) have leaked into the controller, but I think the benefit to code clarity outweighs that.